# Delete ptr resolves in an access-violation exception writing to 0

Tags: c++, exception, access-violation, heap-memory, delete-operator

I got the following code in which last statement I try to delete a pointer to dynamically created memory.

But as soon as I get to the instruction a Access Violation exception is raised saying :

> Unhandled exception at 0x0094c91f in
>   Server.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000000.

But when I step through it with the debugger it contains a valid address with valid data in it... I don't realize what I'm doing fatally wrong here...

Any suggestions?

```
void CServer::HandleAcceptRequest(ACCEPT_REQUEST* pRequest)
{
    //Add the new connection socket to the connection handler
    m_pConnectionHandler->AddConnection(pRequest->m_NewConnection);
    //Associate the new connections´ socket handle with the IOCP
    if(!m_pCompletionPort->AssociateHandle((HANDLE)pRequest->m_NewConnection, 0))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Could not associate a socket handle with the completion port", "", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
        DebugBreak();
    }


    //Create a new COMM_REQUEST and initialize a Recv-Request
    COMM_REQUEST* pCommRequest = new COMM_REQUEST;
    memset(pCommRequest, 0, sizeof(COMM_REQUEST));
    pCommRequest->Socket = pRequest->m_NewConnection;
    pCommRequest->m_RequestType = BASIC_REQUEST::RECV;

    WSABUF* buf = new WSABUF;
    buf->buf = pCommRequest->cBuf;
    buf->len = Inc::COMMUNICATION_BUFFER_SIZE;
    DWORD dwFlags = 0;
    if(WSARecv(pCommRequest->Socket, buf, 1, NULL, &dwFlags, pCommRequest, NULL))
    {
        DWORD dwRet = WSAGetLastError();
        if(dwRet != WSA_IO_PENDING)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "WSARecv() failed", "", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK);
            DebugBreak();
        }
    };

    //Delete the old ACCEPT_REQUEST structure
    delete pRequest;
}
```

**EDIT:** I did allocate the memory in another function in the main thread

```
bool CConnectionHandler::AcceptNewConnection(SOCKET ListenSocket, unsigned nCount)
{
    DWORD dwBytesReceived = 0;
    ACCEPT_REQUEST* pOverlapped = nullptr;

    for(unsigned n = 0; n < nCount; n++)
    {
        dwBytesReceived = 0;
        pOverlapped = new ACCEPT_REQUEST;
        memset(pOverlapped, 0, sizeof(ACCEPT_REQUEST));
        pOverlapped->m_RequestType = ACCEPT_REQUEST::ACCEPT;

        //add the ListenSocket to the request
        pOverlapped->m_ListenSocket = ListenSocket;
        //invalidate the new connection socket
        pOverlapped->m_NewConnection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if(pOverlapped->m_NewConnection == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            delete pOverlapped;
            return false;
        }

        // call 'AcceptEx'
        if(m_lpfnAcceptEx(pOverlapped->m_ListenSocket, pOverlapped->m_NewConnection, pOverlapped->cOutputBuffer, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in) + 16, sizeof(sockaddr_in) + 16, &dwBytesReceived, pOverlapped) == FALSE)
        {
            DWORD dwRet = WSAGetLastError();
            if(dwRet == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
                continue;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
};
```

EDIT2: the threads code to do with giving the parameter to the function...

```
unsigned int WINAPI ServerThreadFunc(void* pvArgs)
{
    CServer* pServer = (CServer*)pvArgs;        // pointer to the server object
    DWORD dwBytes = 0;
    ULONG_PTR ulKey;
    OVERLAPPED* pOverlapped = nullptr;
    bool bLooping = true;

    while(bLooping)
    {
        //TODO: Add code (ServerThreadFunc)
        if(!pServer->m_pCompletionPort->GetCompletionStatus(&dwBytes, &ulKey, &pOverlapped, INFINITE))
        {
            //TODO: Set some error variable or flag an error event to notify the main thread
            DebugBreak();
        }

        //check type of request
        switch(((BASIC_REQUEST*)pOverlapped)->m_RequestType)
        {
        case BASIC_REQUEST::ACCEPT:
            {
                // TODO: Handle AcceptEx-request
                pServer->HandleAcceptRequest(static_cast<ACCEPT_REQUEST*>(pOverlapped));
```

Comment: Where did you allocate that memory?

Comment: Where does pRequest come from? It just shows up like an unwelcomed guest in the code! :)

Comment: Fine, but where does pRequest come from? Still missing it.

Comment: now ther it is... its a parameter

Comment: its given from the OVERLAPPED via an I/O-Completion port

Comment: So, what is the relationship between the first piece of code and the second one? You said that it is allocated in the second piece, but I don't see a `pRequest` variable anywhere in the second piece. "A parameter"? Where? I don't see any parameters called `pRequest` anywhere.

Comment: ok, added the last piece of code... should make it clear now...

Comment: Deleted my previous answer because the code keeps changing.  When the question settles down, I'll come back.

Comment: So, what is `AcceptNewConnection` function is doing here (second piece of code)? I don't see it called from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there's no way to really figure anything out from bits and pieces you provided.

However, in the third piece of code you have this call

```
pServer->HandleAcceptRequest(static_cast<ACCEPT_REQUEST*>(pOverlapped));
```

This call will destroy the `*pOverlapped` object by calling `delete` on it. (Remember that at the very end of `HandleAcceptRequest` you do `delete pRequest`, where `pRequest` is the parameter of `HandleAcceptRequest`).

This will make `pOverlapped` a dangling pointer that points to dead memory. I don't see any place in your code where you would re-initialize that dangling pointer or set it to null.

If you don't re-initialize it, then the next access to `*pOverlapped` in the cycle will access dead memory (which might appear to "work") and the next attempt to `delete` it again will most likely crash. If the next `delete` attempt is the one at the end of `HandleAcceptRequest` again, then the behavior will probably be exactly as what you originally described.

Comment: why does this call "delete" on it?

Comment: @Incubbus: Because you yourself call `delete` on it at the end of `HandleAcceptRequest`. The very `delete` you were asking about, remember?

Comment: Personally, I don't like functions that take pointers to data allocated elsewhere and `delete` them inside the function body.  This prevents you from passing a pointer to something on the stack, makes bugs like this more likely, and makes it hard to remember if you've already `delete`d something that you needed to (without `delete`-ing things that you shouldn't).  Whoever allocated should deallocate, when possible, probably with a smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
OVERLAPPED* pOverlapped = nullptr;
..
pServer->m_pCompletionPort->GetCompletionStatus(&dwBytes, &ulKey, &pOverlapped, INFINITE);
```

Ok. It seems you are deleting the wrong pointer. The one you are deleting inside HandleAcceptRequest() is no longer a pointer to an OVERLAPPED, since the pointer has been casted from OVERLAPPED* to ACCEPT_REQUEST*.

Is GetCompletionStatus() your own?